# japanese input display outside of TextField created into ScrollPane

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm new to ActionScript 2.0. plz kindly help me.
I have created the MainMovieClip and Scrollbar as follow ....

my problem is that when I input japanese characters,the characters display at the top corner of the swf until I confirm the input.
how can I do it??
if I install FlashPlayer "flashplayer10_1_rc2_plugin_041910", then the japanese characters display in the textfield normally....why is that???

plz..help me.
with flash player 10.0, I can't input the japanese characters in the textfield.

var mcMain:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("mcMain", this.getNextHighestDepth());
scrp.contentPath = "scrollMovieClip";
mcMain = scrp.content;

var textholder:TextField = mcMain.createTextField("txt", mcMain.getNextHighestDepth(), 50, 50, 100, 50);
mcMain.txt.setFocus();
mcMain.txt.type = "input";
mcMain.txt.wordWrap = true;
mcMain.txt.multiline = true;
mcMain.txt.background = true;
mcMain.txt.border = true;
mcMain.txt.selectable = true;

thanks in advance...anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. What was the solution for me was to embed the font. I had a _sans device font which didn't work, changing it to a Japanese character compatible (such as MS Gothic) and then embed all Japanese characters solved the problem in Flash player 10.0.